# ReferenceError: contract is not defined

Tags: nft

[image]I was doing the Nader Dabit NFT marketplace tutorial [link](https://youtu.be/GKJBEEXUha0?t=4788) and got this error `ReferenceError: contract is not defined` in my `index.js` at `async function loadNFTs() {`

My full code `index.js`;

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal'

import {
  nftmarketaddress, nftaddress
} from '../config'
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
import NFT from "../artifacts/contracts/NFT.sol/NFT.json"
import Market from "../artifacts/contracts/NFTMarket.sol/NFTMarket.json"

export default function Home() {
  const [nfts, setNfts] = useState([])
  const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState('not-loaded')
  useEffect(() => {
    loadNFTs()
  }, [])
  async function loadNFTs() {
    /* create a generic provider and query for unsold market items */
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider()
    const tokencontract = new ethers.Contract(nftaddress, NFT.abi, provider)
    const marketContract = new ethers.Contract(nftmarketaddress, Market.abi, provider)
    const data = await contract.fetchMarketItems()

    /*
    *  map over items returned from smart contract and format 
    *  them as well as fetch their token metadata
    */
    const items = await Promise.all(data.map(async i => {
      const tokenUri = await contract.tokenURI(i.tokenId)
      const meta = await axios.get(tokenUri)
      let price = ethers.utils.formatUnits(i.price.toString(), 'ether')
      let item = {
        price,
        tokenId: i.tokenId.toNumber(),
        seller: i.seller,
        owner: i.owner,
        image: meta.data.image,
        name: meta.data.name,
        description: meta.data.description,
      }
      return item
    }))
    setNfts(items)
    setLoadingState('loaded')
  }
  if (loadingState === "loaded" && !nfts.length) return (
    <h1 className='px-20 py-10 text-3xl'>No itmes in marketplace</h1>
  )

  async function buyNft(nft) {
    /* needs the user to sign the transaction, so will use Web3Provider and sign it */
    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal()
    const connection = await web3Modal.connect()
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
    const signer = provider.getSigner()
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(marketplaceAddress, NFTMarketplace.abi, signer)

    /* user will be prompted to pay the asking proces to complete the transaction */
    const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(nft.price.toString(), 'ether')
    const transaction = await contract.createMarketSale(nft.tokenId, {
      value: price
    })
    await transaction.wait()
    loadNFTs()
  }
  if (loadingState === 'loaded' && !nfts.length) return (<h1 className="px-20 py-10 text-3xl">No items in marketplace</h1>)
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center">
      <div className="px-4" style={{ maxWidth: '1600px' }}>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-4 pt-4">
          {
            nfts.map((nft, i) => (
              <div key={i} className="border shadow rounded-xl overflow-hidden">
                <img src={nft.image} />
                <div className="p-4">
                  <p style={{ height: '64px' }} className="text-2xl font-semibold">{nft.name}</p>
                  <div style={{ height: '70px', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
                    <p className="text-gray-400">{nft.description}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="p-4 bg-black">
                  <p className="text-2xl font-bold text-white">{nft.price} Matic</p>
                  <button className="mt-4 w-full bg-pink-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-12 rounded" onClick={() => buyNft(nft)}>Buy</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are just a couple of places where you used `contract` in the `loadNFTs` method without `contract` being defined. We have `tokenContract` and `marketContract` available in the scope of the `loadNFTs` function and don't have a variable called `contract` we can use. The places where you're using `contract` in the `loadNFTs` method just need to be replaced with `marketContract` and `tokenContract` where appropriate :)

```js
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal'

import {
  nftmarketaddress, nftaddress
} from '../config'

import NFT from "../artifacts/contracts/NFT.sol/NFT.json"
import Market from "../artifacts/contracts/NFTMarket.sol/NFTMarket.json"

export default function Home() {
  const [nfts, setNfts] = useState([])
  const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState('not-loaded')
  useEffect(() => {
    loadNFTs()
  }, [])
  async function loadNFTs() {
    /* create a generic provider and query for unsold market items */
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider()
    const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(nftaddress, NFT.abi, provider)
    const marketContract = new ethers.Contract(nftmarketaddress, Market.abi, provider)
    // `marketContract` instead of `contract`
    const data = await marketContract.fetchMarketItems()

    /*
    *  map over items returned from smart contract and format 
    *  them as well as fetch their token metadata
    */
    const items = await Promise.all(data.map(async i => {
      // `tokenContract` rather than `contract` here
      const tokenUri = await tokenContract.tokenURI(i.tokenId)
      const meta = await axios.get(tokenUri)
      let price = ethers.utils.formatUnits(i.price.toString(), 'ether')
      let item = {
        price,
        tokenId: i.tokenId.toNumber(),
        seller: i.seller,
        owner: i.owner,
        image: meta.data.image,
        name: meta.data.name,
        description: meta.data.description,
      }
      return item
    }))
    setNfts(items)
    setLoadingState('loaded')
  }
  if (loadingState === "loaded" && !nfts.length) return (
    <h1 className='px-20 py-10 text-3xl'>No itmes in marketplace</h1>
  )

  async function buyNft(nft) {
    /* needs the user to sign the transaction, so will use Web3Provider and sign it */
    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal()
    const connection = await web3Modal.connect()
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
    const signer = provider.getSigner()
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(marketplaceAddress, NFTMarketplace.abi, signer)

    /* user will be prompted to pay the asking proces to complete the transaction */
    const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(nft.price.toString(), 'ether')
    const transaction = await contract.createMarketSale(nft.tokenId, {
      value: price
    })
    await transaction.wait()
    loadNFTs()
  }
  if (loadingState === 'loaded' && !nfts.length) return (<h1 className="px-20 py-10 text-3xl">No items in marketplace</h1>)
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center">
      <div className="px-4" style={{ maxWidth: '1600px' }}>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-4 pt-4">
          {
            nfts.map((nft, i) => (
              <div key={i} className="border shadow rounded-xl overflow-hidden">
                <img src={nft.image} />
                <div className="p-4">
                  <p style={{ height: '64px' }} className="text-2xl font-semibold">{nft.name}</p>
                  <div style={{ height: '70px', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
                    <p className="text-gray-400">{nft.description}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="p-4 bg-black">
                  <p className="text-2xl font-bold text-white">{nft.price} Matic</p>
                  <button className="mt-4 w-full bg-pink-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-12 rounded" onClick={() => buyNft(nft)}>Buy</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hey :) I followed your suggestion by replacing contract with tokenContract and marketContract. Now I got the error: Error: resolver or addr is not configured for ENS name (argument="name", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.2)

Comment: I've run into that error more than a few times and it threw me for a loop at first. The error message tells you a few useful things about what's going on. First, the actual error message is saying there is no address or resolved setup for the ENS name you provided. In this case, that means you are declaring a contract and are passing in something other than an address for the `addressOrName` parameter. As a result, the contract library will try to resolve your input as a name rather than an address and if it can't resolve the name you passed in back to an address, that error is thrown.

Comment: The second thing that error tells you is the name of the invalid argument, in this case "name". The third is the value of that argument. This is the crux of your issue, it is an empty string (`value=""`). The fourth thing the error is telling you is the library and version the error came from. Using this information, one can find the source code that throws the error in [ethersproject/contracts](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/ef1b28e958b50cea7ff44da43b3c5ff054e4b483/packages/contracts/lib/index.js#L674).

Comment: Long story short, you are missing values for `nftmarketaddress` and/or `nftaddress` in your `../config` file. When you try to declare `new Contract` using those values, they are empty and as a result the contract declaration fails with the error you provided.

Comment: Yes, this fixed my problem. Tanks :)

Comment: Happy to help! If that answered your question then feel free to accept it as the answer so future readers will be directed to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Now I got the error `Error: resolver or addr is not configured for ENS name (argument="name", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.2)`

My updated `index.js`

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal'

import {
  nftmarketaddress, nftaddress
} from '../config'

import NFT from "../artifacts/contracts/NFT.sol/NFT.json"
import Market from "../artifacts/contracts/NFTMarket.sol/NFTMarket.json"

export default function Home() {
  const [nfts, setNfts] = useState([])
  const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState('not-loaded')
  useEffect(() => {
    loadNFTs()
  }, [])
  async function loadNFTs() {
    /* create a generic provider and query for unsold market items */
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider()
    const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(nftaddress, NFT.abi, provider)
    const marketContract = new ethers.Contract(nftmarketaddress, Market.abi, provider)
    const data = await marketContract.fetchMarketItems()

    /*
    *  map over items returned from smart contract and format 
    *  them as well as fetch their token metadata
    */
    const items = await Promise.all(data.map(async i => {
      const tokenUri = await tokenContract.tokenURI(i.tokenId)
      const meta = await axios.get(tokenUri)
      let price = ethers.utils.formatUnits(i.price.toString(), 'ether')
      let item = {
        price,
        tokenId: i.tokenId.toNumber(),
        seller: i.seller,
        owner: i.owner,
        image: meta.data.image,
        name: meta.data.name,
        description: meta.data.description,
      }
      return item
    }))
    setNfts(items)
    setLoadingState('loaded')
  }
  if (loadingState === "loaded" && !nfts.length) return (
    <h1 className='px-20 py-10 text-3xl'>No itmes in marketplace</h1>
  )

  async function buyNft(nft) {
    /* needs the user to sign the transaction, so will use Web3Provider and sign it */
    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal()
    const connection = await web3Modal.connect()
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
    const signer = provider.getSigner()
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(marketplaceAddress, NFTMarketplace.abi, signer)

    /* user will be prompted to pay the asking proces to complete the transaction */
    const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(nft.price.toString(), 'ether')
    const transaction = await contract.createMarketSale(nft.tokenId, {
      value: price
    })
    await transaction.wait()
    loadNFTs()
  }
  if (loadingState === 'loaded' && !nfts.length) return (<h1 className="px-20 py-10 text-3xl">No items in marketplace</h1>)
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center">
      <div className="px-4" style={{ maxWidth: '1600px' }}>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-4 pt-4">
          {
            nfts.map((nft, i) => (
              <div key={i} className="border shadow rounded-xl overflow-hidden">
                <img src={nft.image} />
                <div className="p-4">
                  <p style={{ height: '64px' }} className="text-2xl font-semibold">{nft.name}</p>
                  <div style={{ height: '70px', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
                    <p className="text-gray-400">{nft.description}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="p-4 bg-black">
                  <p className="text-2xl font-bold text-white">{nft.price} Matic</p>
                  <button className="mt-4 w-full bg-pink-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-12 rounded" onClick={() => buyNft(nft)}>Buy</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Since this is a separate issue, ideally this should probably be posted as a separate question. I answered it in the comments below my answer but it really is a different issue altogether.